# How to append letters in a tag on the same line

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I'm building a keyboard function as you see on mobile. So far I got a working keyboard that appends the letters to `div p` were I wanted it to go to.

This was my original keyboard without regex:https://jsfiddle.net/yxdehb5p/

When I use regex all letters becomes uppercases: see: https://jsfiddle.net/L9wL6f66/

The regex is doing good because the problem is after each hit the next letter hits a new line in the developer tools:

This is how it looks like inside the developer tools:

```
<div id="result">
    <p>
       "Q"  
       "W"
       "E"
       "."
       "R"
       "T"
       "Y"
   </p>
</div>
```

While this is the result I want to have:

```
<div id="result">
    <p>
       "Qwe. Rty"  
   </p>
</div>
```

What is causing this behaviour?

**Edit:**

Maybe I was unclear. I don't want it to look good in my console.log or dev tools but on screen. But I know this is probably due to my regex. Why does my regex make it uppercase all the time. Btw I'm very bad with understanding regex.

Comment: It's because you're using `append()`. However you should note that the whitespace in a HTML document is mostly ignored so it will make absolutely no difference to the outcome.

Comment: That's just how the dev tool displays your markup since you're appending text nodes. If you copy the outerHTML of the element, you will see that it is equivalent to `<p>Qwe. Rty</p>`

Comment: @David Thomas Just like in the fiddles. It will be displayed on a line. If I add regex to it all the letters become capitals so I thought the browser does see it as entering a new line thus using regex to make it capitalized.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something, but the different letter-cases would seem to be due to: `$result.replace($re, function(x){return x.toUpperCase();});`.

Comment: @DavidThomas I tried this. Also tried to rename it and thinking it maybe causing sort of an error. In your instance I don't think he sees that line of $results and just skips the regex.

Answer (score -1):

Very Simple Solution, below is updated code.

```
var c = 0;
    $(".ui-keyboard-1 button").add(".ui-keyboard-2 button").add(".ui-keyboard-3 button").click(function () {
        c++;

        if ($(this).hasClass('ui-keyboard-noresult')) {
            return;
        }
        $('.ui-keyboard-space').click(function () {
            $('.result p:last').append(' ');
        });

        $(this).val('span');
        $result = $(this).find('span').text().toLowerCase();
        $re = /(^|\. *)([a-z])/g;
        $result = $result.replace($re, function (x) {
            return x.toUpperCase();
        });



        $(".result p:last").append($result);

                //debug
        if(c > 1){
            console.clear();
        }
        console.log($('.result p:last').html());
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: Please describe what the problem was and why your code fixes it. We're here to educate people, not simply dump code.

Comment: I'm happy you thinking with me. But that's not exactly what I wanted. I thought the problem was because of that behaviour. I tried your method out and I get a neat console.log but still get back uppercase letters. I want a tidy string with uppercases when regex is called otherwise only lowercases.